# WooCommerce - t.product_variations is undefined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a WooCommerce website with a custom theme (copied the templates etc)

Anyhow, when viewing a product with variations, I am unable to see the cart button. Once my selection is made, no cart button appears.

There is a JS error: `t.product_variations is undefined`.

All variations are set correctly.

I've read of many threads saying the cart button does not appear, but nothing so far seemes to have solved my specific problem - and no mentioned of my JS error. Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Checked the wp_footer() function is called (it is)
2. Removed all of my own JS to avoid possible collisions (doesn't make any difference)
3. Made sure all product options have a price etc (tried with and without)
4. Tried disabling plugins (only one other plugin used - Advanced Custom Fields - makes no difference)
5. Switched to a default theme 'twentytwelve'. When I do this, **it does work**...

So, switching theme indicates to me that I may have removed something or destoryed something causing this problem in my theme, but I cannot understand what or how.

I am using the latest WP installation and the latest WooCommerce plugin available as of this writing.

I would really appreciate some help on this! *Anything* really to lead me on the right path.

Many thanks,
Mikey.

**Screenshot of error:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a fix for this, but not sure why it worked; here it is for anyone getting a similar issue.

Once I updated the plugin to the latest version, I copied the 5 files in the 'add-to-cart' folder of the plugin, to my themes version of the WooCommerce templates, then uploaded them...this seemed to fix it.

Basically, I think that the files I had in my theme, that were designed to override the core WooCommerce templates perhaps had some old code that broke the variations logic.

In other words, make sure that if you're over-riding templates, that they are also up to date as well as the plugins files itself.

**The folder in questions was here:**

/wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/